# port.ReadExisting closes port

Tags: c#, serial-port

```
try
{
    // open device com port
    _port.Open();
}
catch 
{
}

if (_port.IsOpen)
{
    // clear input buffer
    _port.ReadExisting();
    _port.write("c");
}
```

System.InvalidOperationExeption: 'The port is closed'

the port closes after `_port.ReadExisting()` and then trows an exeption in `sendCmd` on a `_port.Write()` (in the example code sendcmd changed to _port.write("c")) due to the _port being closed id like to know the reason why it closes and a fix if the reason why it closes isnt that obvious

Comment: what does sendCmd do?

Comment: well the part that matters is that it uses _port.write() where because of the prior line _port is closed i didnt add the contents of sendcmd because its not relevant to the question

Comment: the exception is thrown in sendCmd, so there might happen relevant things there. The fact that ReadExisting closes the port is just an assumption. There is no reason why ReadExistion would close a port, so we will have to look at the rest of your code. Did you check _port.IsOpen right after ReadExisting? Do you just throw the response away, or do you use DataReceived ?

Comment: i did check using breakpoints as soon as _port.ReadExisting() is run the port closes and just cause you insist ill replaced sendcmd with the port.write that is in sendcmd and the port was closed

Comment: try and replace ReadExisting with [data receive event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8) and check if the problem persists

Comment: i have found a fix that makes me wonder if my code is the cause ill post it as a possible answer but ill still look into this

Comment: @Meow if you found a fix, update your question with it

Answer (score 0):

The only fix so far is `Thread.sleep(1000)` before try catch. Migth have been caused by a _port.close that ran a litte bit after _port.open closing the port making it seem like _port.ReadExisting the next line to run caused it to close.

Comment: Maybe it would help you to solve the problem with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)